# Pact, ensure key names in array

Tags: arrays, pact

If returned json is a map, all key names specified in body response will be proved for existence. So

```
...
"response": 
{
    "status": 200,
    "body": 
    {
        "field1": "value1"
    }
...
```

will ensure, that body contains a key "field1", if it is missing, an error occurs.

But what if response body is an array? I see no chance to test, if all or at least one element in this array have a specific key name. But this is important, I want to be warned if key names in backend are changing, because that would create errors in my application.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `eachLike` to specify that array elements match a particular format. The correct syntax depends on which Pact framework you're using, but with pact-js, you would say:

```
const { somethingLike: like, term, eachLike } = pact
....

willRespondWith: {
   status: 200,
   body: eachLike({
    "field1": "value1"
   })
}
```

Here is the [relevant part of the documentation](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js#match-based-on-arrays).

---

Your example suggests you're writing the Pact file yourself - if this is the case, you can use the `[*]` notation to describe any array element, as described in the [specification](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-specification/tree/version-2):

```
"response": 
{
  "status": 200,
  "body": 
    [ 
      {
        "field1": "value1"
      }
    ],
  ...

  "matchingRules": {
     "$.body": {
       "min": 1,
       "match": "type"
     },
     "$.body[*].field1": {
        "match": "type"
     },
  ...
```

Comment: But this ensures only that type of field1 matches if it is present, not that field1 has to be in the response. So a body with [{}] will not throw an error.

Comment: Are you certain? That's not my reading of [the specification](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-specification/tree/version-2) - the `[*]` should match all elements in the array, and there's no concept of optional fields.